# Change the position of the strip label in ggplot from the top to the bottom?

Tags: r, ggplot2, strip, facet

I know this is not quite a data visualization issue, but the boss asked for it, so I need to figure out if it is possible.

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/a9a28e6b603d3e9d

Comment: ggplot2 is powerful but opinionated software- sometimes it is the ggplot way or no way at all.

Comment: agree, need to do some modification using grid then, another steep learning curve again

Comment: See linked forum post in the comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058839/how-to-display-strip-labels-below-the-plot , which gives the required grid hackery

Comment: Using `gtable` functions, it is easy to move the strip. See  [http://stackoverflow.com/.../how-to-display-strip-labels-below-the-plot-when-faceting/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058839/how-to-display-strip-labels-below-the-plot-when-faceting/29336396#29336396) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008683/ggplot2-using-gtable-to-move-strip-labels-to-top-of-panel-for-facet-grid/29022188#29022188) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853786/how-do-i-plot-charts-with-nested-categories-axes/28868462#28868462)

Comment: And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065319/flip-facet-label-and-x-axis-with-ggplot2?lq=1)

Comment: Could you please un-accept the accepted answer? It’s no longer correct, yet this answer is the top hit when googling for the question.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

An answer for those searching in 2016.

As of `ggplot2` 2.0, the [switch argument](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_grid.html) will do this for `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap`:

> By default, the labels are displayed on the top and right of the plot. If "x", the top labels will be displayed to the bottom. If "y", the right-hand side labels will be displayed to the left. Can also be set to "both".

```
ggplot(...) + ... + facet_grid(facets, switch="both")
```

As of ggplot2 [2.2.0](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/releases/tag/v2.0.0),

> Strips can now be freely positioned in `facet_wrap()` using the 
>   strip.position argument (deprecates `switch`).

Current docs, are still at 2.1, but `strip.position` is [documented](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/facet_wrap.html) on the dev docs.

> By default, the labels are displayed on the top of the plot. Using strip.position it is possible to place the labels on either of the four sides by setting `strip.position = c("top", "bottom", "left", "right")`

```
ggplot(...) + ... + facet_wrap(facets, strip.position="right")
```

Comment: 2020 update - ggplot 3.3 - `facet_grid` [still uses](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html) `switch` with arguments of `x`, `y` or `both`.

Comment: The link for `strip.position` is broken

Comment: Now (with version 3.4.2), options are `switch = ` to "both", "x", or "y"

Answer (score 40):

you can now use `facet_wrap(~var, strip.position = "bottom")`, though for some reason this results in the labels being located above the axis tick mark labels, rather than below (which I think would make more sense), as you can see from my screenshot of a small portion of my graph

[image: screenshot of graph]

If you want to have the label below, you have do to this

```
ggplot(zzz, aes(x = c1, y = c2)) +
  facet_wrap(~ gp, scales = "free", nrow = 3, strip.position = "bottom") +
  geom_point() +
  theme(
    aspect.ratio = 1,
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.placement = "outside"
  )
```

As seen here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2622