# Connect ggplot boxplots using lines and multiple factor

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, data-visualization, boxplot

I'm trying to connect ggplot2 boxplots with geom_lines for multiple factors. I'd been able to accomplish so far to connect all the boxplot with lines, see attach picture. But I wish to connect the only boxplots by their corresponding factor.

[image]

For example for my variable FL, I want to connect only those two boxplot, without connecting them with the remaining variables. Similarly for the variable RW, connecting those two sex boxplot without the remaining others.

```
library("MASS")  
data(crabs)  
melt_crabs <- melt(crabs,id.var=c("sp","sex","index"))   
ggplot(melt_crabs, aes(x = variable, y = value)) +   geom_line(aes(group = index), size = 0.05, alpha = 0.7) +   geom_boxplot(aes(fill = sp), alpha = 0.5) + facet_grid(sex~.)
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?  I hope I'd explain myself the most clear way.

Many thanks and best wishes,

Comment: Your code does not produce the figure you show. I think you just exchanged `sex` and `sp`.

Comment: @Stibu Thanks for replying and editing the code.  I'm new at this and I thought it was displayed my apologies. The used of sex and sp is not impotant. The example here is to have two boxplot in the same factor and connect them. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Stibu's answer is definitely the quickest and cleanest way to get your desired output. Building off his answer, since for a given variable, the plots are no longer next to each other, you might want to put each in their own separate plot. This can be easily by only a minor tweak to the `facet_grid` call in @Stibu's code:

```
ggplot(melt_crabs, aes(x = interaction(sex, variable), y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = sex), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(group = interaction(index, variable)),
            alpha = 0.5, colour = "darkgrey") +
  facet_grid(sp~variable,scales="free_x") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = "")
```

[image]

Also I did some digging if you want to move the top strip to the bottom, it isn't that difficult. Adapting the code from: [How to display strip labels below the plot when faceting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058839/how-to-display-strip-labels-below-the-plot-when-faceting)

We get:

```
p<-ggplot(melt_crabs, aes(x = interaction(sex, variable), y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = sex), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(group = interaction(index, variable)),
            alpha = 0.5, colour = "darkgrey") +
  facet_grid(sp~variable,scales="free_x") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = "")

# Convert the plot to a grob
gt <- ggplotGrob(p)

# Get the positions of the panels in the layout: t = top, l = left, ...
panels <-c(subset(gt$layout, name == "panel", select = t:r))

# Get the strip grob & x-axis label grob
stripGrob = gtable_filter(gt, "strip-top")

#Replace x-axis ticks with strip
gt = gtable_add_grob(gt, stripGrob, t = max(panels$b)+1, l = min(panels$l), r = max(panels$r))

# remove the old strip
gt = gt[-(min(panels$t)-1), ]

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all your help. The use of the interaction() function was what I needed.  

Many thanks and best wishes!

Comment: Excellent idea to use facets! In this situation, there is actually no need any more for `x = interaction(sex, variable)` and you could just use `x = sex`. I cannot exactly reproduce your  plot; which version of ggplot2 are you using? In the newest version, you can move the facet labels to the bottom by using `switch = "x"` in `facet_grid()`. This does not look quite  as nice as your variant, because it leaves the ticks at the bottom. With `scale_x_discrete(labels = NULL, breaks = NULL)` it gets nicer, but your solution still looks more beautiful.

Comment: I was using version 1.0.1 in this example...a little dated I know. But I did not know about the `switch = "x"` functionality in the `facet_grid()`, this is definitely a faster way to get a similar output. Thanks! Also I just installed the latest version of ggplot2 and latest R version and the same code seems to be working for me, my only thought is maybe we differ on what grid version we're using? I'm using version 0.2.0.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of way to connect the points in exactly the plot that you produced. But I can show you how to do something similar.

The difficulty is that all the points that belong to a *pair* of boxplots share the same x-coordinate (that is, the same value for `variable`). Therefore I have used `interaction(sex, variable)` as the x-coordinate, such that each boxplot has its own x-value. This means, however, that the paired boxplots are less visible. On the other hand, the connecting lines work in the other direction.

In order to plot the lines, they are grouped by `interaction(index, variable)`, which means that data points are connected, when they share the same values for `index` and `variable`.

Enough talk, here's the code:

```
ggplot(melt_crabs, aes(x = interaction(sex, variable), y = value)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = sex), alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_line(aes(group = interaction(index, variable)),
              alpha = 0.5, colour = "darkgrey") +
    facet_grid(sp~.) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = rep(levels(melt_crabs$variable), each = 2))
```

[image]