# How to add a line in boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, mean, boxplot

I would like to add lines between "mean" in my boxplot.

My code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

Gp=factor(c(rep("G1",80),rep("G2",80)))
Fc=factor(c(rep(c(rep("FC1",40),rep("FC2",40)),2)))
Z <-factor(c(rep(c(rep("50",20),rep("100",20)),4)))
Y <- c(0.19 , 0.22 , 0.23 , 0.17 , 0.36 , 0.33 , 0.30 , 0.39 , 0.35 , 0.27 , 0.20 , 0.22 , 0.24 , 0.16 , 0.36 , 0.30 , 0.31 , 0.39 , 0.33 , 0.25 , 0.23 , 0.13 , 0.16 , 0.18 ,  0.20 , 0.16 , 0.15 , 0.09 , 0.18 , 0.21 , 0.20 , 0.14 , 0.17 , 0.18 , 0.22 , 0.16 , 0.14 , 0.11 , 0.18 , 0.21 , 0.30 , 0.36 , 0.40 , 0.42 , 0.26 , 0.23 , 0.25 , 0.30 ,  0.27 , 0.15 , 0.29 , 0.36 , 0.38 , 0.42 , 0.28 , 0.23 , 0.26 , 0.29 , 0.24 , 0.17 , 0.24 , 0.14 , 0.17 , 0.16 , 0.15 , 0.21 , 0.19 , 0.15 , 0.16 , 0.13 , 0.25 , 0.12 ,  0.15 , 0.15 , 0.14 , 0.21 , 0.20 , 0.13 , 0.14 , 0.12 , 0.29 , 0.29 , 0.29 , 0.24 , 0.21 , 0.23 , 0.25 , 0.33 , 0.30 , 0.27 , 0.31 , 0.27 , 0.28 , 0.25 , 0.22 , 0.23 , 0.23 , 0.33 , 0.29 , 0.28 , 0.12 , 0.28 , 0.22 , 0.19 , 0.22 , 0.14 , 0.15 , 0.15 , 0.21 , 0.25 , 0.11 , 0.27 , 0.22 , 0.17 , 0.21 , 0.15 , 0.16 , 0.15 , 0.20 , 0.24 ,  0.24 , 0.25 , 0.36 , 0.24 , 0.34 , 0.22 , 0.27 , 0.26 , 0.23 , 0.28 , 0.24 , 0.23 , 0.36 , 0.23 , 0.35 , 0.21 , 0.25 , 0.26 , 0.23 , 0.28 , 0.24 , 0.23 , 0.09 , 0.16 , 0.16 , 0.14 , 0.18 , 0.18 , 0.18 , 0.12 , 0.22 , 0.23 , 0.09 , 0.17 , 0.15 , 0.13 , 0.17 , 0.19 , 0.17 , 0.11)
X <- factor(c(rep(c(rep("B1",10),rep("B2",10)),8)))
DATA=data.frame(Y,X,Z,Fc,Gp)
p <- qplot(X, Y, data=DATA, geom="boxplot", fill=Z, na.rm = TRUE, 
                    outlier.size = NA, outlier.colour = NA)  +
          facet_grid(Gp ~ Fc)+ theme_light()+scale_colour_gdocs()+
          theme(legend.position="bottom") + 
          stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=23, position = position_dodge(width = .75))
```

I have:

[image]

And the expected plot I want:

[image]

I tried this

```
p + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", aes(group = factor(Z)))
```

and this

```
p + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", aes(group = factor(X)))
```

but none of the above worked. Instead, I received the following error message:

> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to
>   adjust the group aesthetic? geom_path: Each group consists of only one
>   observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic? geom_path:
>   Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the
>   group aesthetic? geom_path: Each group consists of only one
>   observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try a tidyverse solution as well:

```
library(tidyverse)
DATA %>% 
   ggplot() + 
   geom_boxplot(aes(X, Y, fill=Z)) +
   stat_summary(aes(X, Y,fill=Z),fun.y = mean, geom = "point",
                position=position_nudge(x=c(-0.185,0.185))) +
   geom_segment(data=. %>%
                  group_by(X, Z, Gp , Fc) %>% 
                  summarise(M=mean(Y)) %>% 
                  ungroup() %>% 
                  mutate(Z=paste0("C",Z)) %>% 
                  spread(Z, M), aes(x = as.numeric(X)-0.185, y = C100, 
                    xend = as.numeric(X)+0.185, yend = C50)) +
   facet_grid(Gp ~ Fc)
```

[image]

The idea is the same as in the answer of d.b.. Create a data.frame for the geom_segment call. the advantage is the dplyr workflow. So everything is done in one run.

```
DATA %>% 
  group_by(X, Z, Gp , Fc) %>% 
  summarise(M=mean(Y)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Z=paste0("C",Z)) %>% 
  spread(Z, M) 
# A tibble: 8 x 5
       X     Gp     Fc  C100   C50
* <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     B1     G1    FC1 0.169 0.281
2     B1     G1    FC2 0.170 0.294
3     B1     G2    FC1 0.193 0.270
4     B1     G2    FC2 0.168 0.269
5     B2     G1    FC1 0.171 0.276
6     B2     G1    FC2 0.161 0.292
7     B2     G2    FC1 0.188 0.269
8     B2     G2    FC2 0.163 0.264
```

Or you can try a slighlty different approach compared to Julius' answer. Add breaks and labels to get the expected output and play around with some offset on a numeric `X2` and the width parameter within the boxplot function to get the boxes plotted together.

```
DATA %>% 
  mutate(X2=as.numeric(interaction(Z, X))) %>% 
  mutate(X2=ifelse(Z==100, X2 + 0.2, X2 - 0.2)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(X2, Y, fill=Z, group=X2)) + 
   geom_boxplot(width=0.6) +
   stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point") +
   stat_summary(aes(group = X),fun.y = mean, geom = "line") +
   facet_grid(Gp ~ Fc) +
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1.5,3.5), labels = c("B1","B2"),
                        minor_breaks = NULL, limits=c(0.5,4.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Jimbou  for your help and your clear answer ! but I don't understand why you add X2+0.2 and X2-0.2 and breaks = c (1.5,3.5) ?

Comment: The `breaks = c (1.5,3.5)` were set as you wanted a grouped boxplot of B1 and of B2. Thus this is the value inbetween. The offset of `+/-0.2` together with the `width=0.6` were chosen as then the boxes for F100 and F50 are closely plotted side by side.

Comment: @Sh.student Omit the `scale_x_continuous` part, then it should be clear.

Comment: with your code, can we eliminate or not display the outliers ? using for example :  outlier.size = NA, outlier.colour = NA ...

Comment: Yes of course. Add `outlier.color = NA` to the boxplot function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166046/discussion-between-sh-student-and-jimbou).

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative:

```
DATA$U <- paste(X, Z) # Extra interaction
qplot(U, Y, data = DATA, geom = "boxplot", fill = Z, na.rm = TRUE, 
      outlier.size = NA, outlier.colour = NA) +
  facet_grid(Gp ~ Fc) + theme_light() + scale_colour_gdocs() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", shape = 23, position = position_dodge(width = .75)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", aes(group = X)) + # Lines
  scale_x_discrete(labels = rep(levels(X), each = 2)) + xlab("X") # Some fixes
```

[image]

Comment: Good alternative ! but on the x-axis I want to have only B1 and B2 no B1 B1 and B2 B2, I mean, I want to grouped both boxplot of B1 and of B2, as I published in my question. Thank you for your help !

Comment: @Sh.student, I understand, but unfortunately that's the side effect of this approach.

Comment: @Sh.student, https://stackoverflow.com/q/36240695/1320535 is almost a duplicate and the second answer gives more details on my approach.

Answer (score 4):

This is not elegant but try this

```
tmp1 = aggregate(Y~., DATA[DATA$Z == 100,], mean)
tmp2 = aggregate(Y~., DATA[DATA$Z == 50,], mean)
tmp1$X2 = tmp2$X
tmp1$Y2 = tmp2$Y

graphics.off()
ggplot(DATA, aes(x = factor(X), y = Y, fill = Z)) +
    geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, outlier.shape = NA) +
    geom_segment(data = tmp1,
                 aes(x = as.numeric(factor(X)) - 0.125, y = Y,
                     xend = as.numeric(factor(X2)) + 0.125, yend = Y2)) +
    facet_grid(Gp ~ Fc)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, admittedly a bit convoluted, but hopefully it avoids some hardcoding.

The idea is to build a plot object including the `stat_summary` call. From this,  grab relevant data (`ggplot_build(p)$data[[2]]`) to be used for the lines. The second data slot (`[[2]]`) corresponds to the second layer in the plot call, i.e. the `x` and `y` generated by `stat_summary`.

Grab `x` and `y` positions and indices of panel (`PANEL`) and x categories (`group`).

In the data from the plot object, the 'PANEL' and 'group' variables are not given explicitly by their names, but as numbers corresponding to the different combinations of `facet` variables, and variables which eventually will generate a numeric `x` position (here both 'the real' `x` and `fill`).

However, because categorical variables are ordered lexicographically in `ggplot`, we can match the numbers with their corresponding variables. The `.GRP` function in `data.table` is convenient here.

This data can then be used to draw a `geom_line` between the means.

```
# dodge value
pos <- position_dodge(width = 0.75)

# initial plot
p <- ggplot(data = DATA, aes(x = X, y = Y, fill = Z)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.size = NA, outlier.colour = NA, 
               position = pos) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", shape = 23, position = pos) +
  facet_grid(Gp ~ Fc)

# grab relevant data
d <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[2]][ , c("PANEL", "group", "x", "y")]

library(data.table)
setDT(DATA)

# select unique combinations of facet and x variables
# here x includes the fill variable 'Z'
d2 <- unique(DATA[ , .(Gp, Fc, Z, X)])

# numeric index of facet combinations
d2[ , PANEL := .GRP, by = .(Gp, Fc)]

# numeric index of x combinations
d2[ , group := .GRP, by = .(Z, X)]

# add x and y positions by joining on PANEL and group
d2 <- d2[d, on = .(PANEL, group)]

# plot!
p + geom_line(data = d2, aes(x = x, y = y))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have a way of doing this, surely similar to whats have been done, but using `geom_line` and `position_dodge` and data.table

```
library(data.table)
DATA=data.table(Y,X,Z,Fc,Gp)

 qplot(X, Y, data=DATA, geom="boxplot", fill=Z, na.rm = TRUE, 
           outlier.size = NA, outlier.colour = NA)  +
   geom_line(data = DATA[,list(Y = mean(Y)), by = .(X,Z,Fc,Gp)][X == "B1"],aes(X,Y,color = Z),group =1, position = position_dodge(width = .75),color = "black") +
   geom_line(data = DATA[,list(Y = mean(Y)), by = .(X,Z,Fc,Gp)][X == "B2"],aes(X,Y,color = Z),group =1, position = position_dodge(width = .75),color = "black") +
  facet_grid(Gp ~ Fc)+ theme_light()+
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=23, position = position_dodge(width = .75))
```

[image]